# Finitely presented modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I know that one can compute Fitting ideals of a finitely presented module (over a commutative ring with identity). However, are they the only invariants of such a module?

In other words, my question is: *if two finitely presented modules have the same Fitting ideals, then are they isomorphic?* Obviously the answer is yes if the base ring is a PID. If the answer is no, how is a strategy to prove that two f.p. modules with the same Fitting ideals are not isomorphic?

Unfortunately, base change is not useful in this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is no:
*The Fitting ideals of a finitely presented module $M$ over a ring $A$ do no not determine the module*.

Indeed suppose the ring $A$  is connected (no idempotents $\neq0,1$).
Then $all$ finitely presented projective modules $M$ of rank $r$ have the same sequence of Fitting modules, namely
$$F^0(M)=F^1(M)=... =F^{r-1} (M)=0\subsetneq F^r(M)=F^{r+1}(M)=...=A                        $$

You can find the proof in Eisenbud's [Commutative Algebra](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Fm_yPgZBucMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=eisenbud&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=ClMIT5jQEsrIhAfu_4yfCQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=eisenbud&f=false), Proposition 20.8, which *Google books* is kind enough to show you in its entirety, proof included.

Comment: Dear Georges: Could you give an example of non-isomorphic finitely presented projective modules of same rank? Thank you in advance. (+1 of course!)

Comment: Here is a direct link to [the proposition Georges refers to](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Fm_yPgZBucMC&lpg=PP1&dq=eisenbud&hl=fr&pg=PA500#v=onepage&q=eisenbud&f=false).

Comment: @Georges, thank you a lot! My question was quite stupid, sorry.
To Pierre, take a non principal ideal in a Dedekind domain: for example, $A = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $I = (2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$.

Comment: Dear @Andrea: Thanks! By the way, I found your question very interesting (and upvoted it).

Comment: Dear @Andrea, your question was not stupid at all. On the contrary: although it is quite natural,  I have never seen it mentioned in a  book. Moreover it  is definitely not trivial: I know no simpler way to answer it than to invoke the beautiful but somewhat unexpected theorem mentioned in the answer. ( Needless to say, I have upvoted it)